# Using 0xFFFF00000001LL in Java

Tags: java

In the native Part of my Java JNI project I have something like:

```
#   define BS_ANALOG_AUDIO_PLAYBACK                 0xFFFF00000001LL
```

In C++ I will use it as:

```
int nError = AnalyseCapability(BS_ANALOG_AUDIO_PLAYBACK, &bRes);

Declaration:
typedef long long int           int64;
AnalyseCapability(int64 nCapabilityName, BS_BOOL * pbResult);
```

But how I can use this in Java to send it to JNI function? I tried

```
int capa = 0xFFFF00000001LL;
long capa = 0xFFFF00000001LL;
```

But Java do not like it. Any suggestion?

Comment: A 64-bit value in Java is a `long`.  A long value is prefixed with only one `L`.

Comment: `long capa = 0xFFFF00000001L;`